# Collision detect on irregular shapes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, uiview, uiimage

I've been working for a while on a very complicated problem. Now, i'm posting here, hoping that someone can give me an hint for the solution.

The problem, as stated on the topic, is about collision detect on irregular shapes (UIView).

What i've done so far:

Using [THIS](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/03/irregularly-shaped-uibuttons.html) as starting point, i've done an UIImageView subclass that can check for alpha/non-alpha points on his frame property. On a UIPanGestureRecognizer selector of my object, i've attached a check to see if i moved it on a obstacle (not alpha) or not:

```
- (void)panning:(id)sender {
    UIPanGestureRecognizer = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender;

    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        startPoint = CGPointZero;
        oldPoint = CGPointZero;
        return;
    }
    actualPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:parentView];

    if(CGAffineTransformIsIdentity(panning)) {
        panning = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(actualPoint.x - startPoint.x, actualPoint.y - startPoint.y);
    } else {
        panning = CGAffineTransformTranslate(panning, actualPoint.x - startPoint.x, actualPoint.y - startPoint.y);
    }

    [self setTransform:panning];

    for(UIView *anObstacle in obstaclesArray) {
        CGRect intersection = CGRectIntersection(self.frame, anObstacle.frame);
        if([anObstacle checkAlpha:intersection] != NULL) { 
            NSLog(@"BOOOOOOOOOOOM");
        }
    }
}
```

All is working well, except for performance. The Check is TOO slow for a production application.

Is there any workaround or solution that i don't know, in order to solve this issue?

Hoping to be clear,
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Can you generate a circle around the irregular objects to reduce initial computation, and then if there is collision with the circle, then go ahead and check if it is actually colliding. The set of points checked could potentially be reduced based on where on the circle a collision was detected.

Comment: i already compute the CGIntersect area. As far as i know this kind of interpolation is pretty good for reducing the computational area. Thanks for the cent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the final task and I'm not very skilled in iOS programming, but once I wrote the collision detection method for a OpenGL game. It was pretty similar to your task, I suppose: I wanted to check the collision of two somehow transformed (rotation, scale) alpha-channeled images. The basic idea behind the check was:

1. Quick check collision between the bounding rects.
2. Determine the collision areas for every image and do a per-pixel check.

Since you have UIView instead of bitmaps, I can suggest you either to review the architecture and use Images/Layers (if you have a kind of a game) or maybe prepare some bitmasks for the views. Low-level access to the collision mask (alpha channel) is very fast and such a check won't hurt the performance. Also, a far as I see, you don't need rotation matrix - this simplifies the task even more.

My old game code worked at 10-years old machines and it was able to check collisions for hundreds of objects in 30fps.

At last, if your task is the game or similar - haven't you thought about using some kind of game engine? Maybe **cocos2d**?

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply. Definitely, i'm working on a game. However, i don't want to switch to cocos2d since i want to explore the limits of the UIKit (and its performance). Of course, i'm working on CGImage, instead of whole UIImage, and i'm caching the computed CGImage. However, the performance with about 200 obstacles and my object are very poor

Comment: @valvoline, have you tried time profiling in the Instruments? It's a good tool to check what is causing the bad performance. I'm not sure how do you read the pixels of the image, getting the low-level byte* is the best choice, I guess.